# operator () on class instance in Python

Tags: python, class

I am doing a tutorial. The source code for the tutorial is on
https://github.com/adventuresinML/adventures-in-ml-code/blob/master/pytorch_nn.py

If you look at line 63, it has `net_out = net(data)`. `net` is an instance of `Net` class. What does `net(data)` do? I have never seen this syntax before.

Comment: it is passing the data as  object to class Net

Comment: The tutorial seems to suggest it is passing it into the `forward` method of `Net` class. Is this true, and if so, I don't quite understand how it is doing that, even after reading the "How to use __call__" thread. `Net` class also does not have a `__call__()` function, so I am a little bit confused how this object is callable.

Comment: consider this [examlpe](https://ideone.com/MaAvmp)you will understand what is happening there .

Comment: I understand this example. You created an instance of `Add`, and then you called the member function `sol`. But I still don't understand how this relates to the above code?

Comment: you r passing `touch.nn.module` ( which is `data`)to your NET CLass. which is interting the class and doing tasks.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. The `net` instance is being used a callable object correct? If so, how is this possible with `Net` class does not have a `__call__` method?